# Newly registered users are not being reflected in the database in 'Django Administration' page after I login as an admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am trying to build a user login/signup page using Django. Everything works fine except when I try to register new users by clicking on the register button, the newly registered users are not being reflected in the database in 'Django Administration' page after I login as an admin. Please help.

Here's my code:
urls.py-login

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path,include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('accounts/', include('accounts.urls'))
]
```

urls.py-accounts

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.indexView, name = "home"),
    path('dashboard/', views.dashboardView, name = "dashboard"),
    # path('login/',),
    path('register/',views.registerView, name = "register_url"),
    # path('logout,'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

# Create your views here.
def indexView(request):
    return render(request, 'index.html')

def dashboardView(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html')

def registerView(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('login_url')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', {'form':form})
```

```
index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Petrol Pump Management System</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% block content %}
        <h1>User Authentication</h1>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>



 register.html

    {% extends 'index.html'%}
    
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Create new account</h1>
        <form method = "POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.as_p}}
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Comment: After a user is registered you redirect to login url but this is commented out. Try to redirect to dashboard instead and see what happens.

Comment: Another suggestion in register.html: change <form method=“post”> to <form method=“post” novalidate>